# NAudio playing 32 bit float IEE

Tags: c#, naudio

I have an application which is generating 32 bit floats (big endian). If I write these to a file and then open them in Audacity the file plays correctly.
I am trying to play the stream using NAudio. If I create a WaveFormat of 24k samples, 32 bit and 2 channels I do hear noise although as it's the wrong format the stream isn't rendering of course, if I create the correct format (IeeeFloatWave) then I don't hear anything at all. I know the samples are arriving correctly as I can save them to disk but I just can't play them. Anybody see what I'm doing that is wrong?

**Updated and solved - little to big endian change is in the feeding routine**

**FloatTo16 bit provider converts format before playing**

```
private bool _streamActive = false;
private BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider = null;
private WaveFloatTo16Provider waveFloatTo16Provider = null;
private WaveOut waveOut = null;
private WaveFormat waveFormat=null;

// ProcessSound is fed incoming byte packets
// (28 bytes header plus 1024 bytes audio)
// by background thread
// Data is converted from little to big endian in background thread
public void ProcessSound(byte[] rxData)
{
    // get data length
    int datalen = rxData.Length;

    // check to activate player
    if (_streamActive == true)
    {
        // add samples to buffer ('28' allows for header information)
        bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(rxData, 28, datalen - 28);
        return;
    }

    // start it going
    waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(24000, 2);

    // create buffer to allow samples to be added
    bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveFormat);

    // convert from 32 bit float to 16 bit PCM
    waveFloatTo16Provider = new WaveFloatTo16Provider(bufferedWaveProvider);

    // add samples to buffer
    bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(rxData, 28, datalen - 28);

    // create waveOut player
    waveOut = new WaveOut();
    waveOut.Init(waveFloatTo16Provider);
    waveOut.Volume = 0.25f;
    waveOut.Play();

    // mark stream is active
    _streamActive = true;
}
```

Comment: Never mind, I found the issue. It was not helped by the 32 bit stream being little endian. I've updated the code to show the solution although I've omitted the little to big endian byte swap as it's trivail

Comment: As a footnote there's no need to actually convert the 32 bit floats to 16 bit PCM, having simply set the endian-ness correctly the stream plays fine with NAudio as 32 bit floats.